# What's the best way to launch files in new tab?

Tags: sharepoint-online

What is the best way to launch files in the browser from a sharepoint site?

Initially I set it up to only launch word documents, but the requirement has changed to be able to launch most office documents and pdf files.

Here's the code I was using:

```
$('#tbDocuments').append("
    <div>
      <a target='_blank' href='https://gumdropsgc.sharepoint.com/sites/Training/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=" + key.FileRef + "&action=default'>
        <span class='docTitle'>" + key.TaskTitle + "</span>
      </a><br/>
      <div class='docDesc'>" + key.TaskDescription + "</div><br/><br/></div>")
```

Update:
I was able to get PDF functionality, where PDFs open in a new tab by simply removing the following string <&action=default>

Comment: Bitspider, do you need to download the files? or do you need to open them in Office Web Apps? of the former is true - https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload

Comment: Just need them to open in the browser in a new tab. If PDF can open in office web apps, then that would work fine.

Comment: right, I think you can open your Excel and Word files in a new tab. As to PDF, can you look the the following link? http://www.pdfsharepoint.com/sharepoint-2010-and-pdf-integration-series-part-1/

Comment: Although this code works for Microsoft Office file types, it did not function for PDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get PDF functionality, where PDFs open in a new tab by simply removing the following string <&action=default>

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post where it forces the PDF and the JPG files to open in a new tab, instead of the same page (default behavior): 
[**How to open files/documents in SharePoint document library is new tab**](http://spshell.blogspot.com/2017/08/how-to-open-filesdocuments-in.html)